# Reference for Algebraic topology books

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

Im beginner in algebraic topology.I have read the general topology book by Munkres  and topology without tears by Morris

I have seen the Allen Hatcher book .It is very tough book ,so i need some easier book

I need references for  very basic books  in Algebraic topology and that book  must contain given topics below

$1.$Homotopy Theory.  Covering spaces, homotopy maps, homotopy equivalence,Contractible spaces, deformation retraction.

$2.$Fundamental Groups: Universal cover and lifting problem for covering maps, Fundamental groups of S1 and Sn.

$3$ .Introduction to Homology Theory.

Comment: Try "A First Course in Algebraic Topology" by Czes Kosniowski. Lots of figures but writes proofs better than Hatcher, overall very friendly.

Comment: Assuming you know point-set topology (basic definitions of topologies, open/closed sets, continuity, product/quotient/subset/disjoint union topologies) I would still recommend Hatcher. You might start with parts of the appendices for background material.

Comment: @IvoTerek      oks thanks for this books let me see this book in online

Comment: @ElliotG   i have try  Allen  hatcher book from chapter 0 .some underlying geometric notion.......that .books contain not detail explaination...so it's very difficult to understand

Comment: @IvoTerek good book ,i will try this book for $ 1/3$ week...after that  i will give my feeback about this book on this comment

Comment: try "topology of surfaces" for a very introduction before diving into a more classic book

Comment: @IvoTerek     I really enjoy this book   wonderful books   more better explaination  than Allen hatcher book...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spanier, Greenburg and Harper, and Munkres are three that come to mind.

There was also one by Fomenko and somebody else (maybe Fuchs) on homotopy theory that had great illustrations.

Comment: The poster asked for an easier book than Hatcher, and I don't think Spanier qualifies. ;)

Comment: You're probably right. But it is the subject itself that is inherently difficult. I am partial to Spanier. He's one of the best professors I ever had. I had a copy of it, but no longer (after all I've been through). @JohnPalmieri